# Making a logotype "pop" off the page

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, logo

I really like the look of the Launchrock logo:

[image: Launchrock logo image]

It's subtle, but it seems to 'pop' off the background. Being that the background is dark, I can't image that they're achieving this with a simple drop shadow. I'm wondering what tools in Photoshop would I need to use to create a subtle 3D effect like they have here?

Comment: is it just me or does the gap in the middle fingers and raised mid section in the rock/devil horns sign make it look like "lawnchrock"? Sounds relaxing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is indeed a simple drop shadow over a dark background with a radial gradient applied to it.

Background:

[image: backing]

With Logo:

[image: logo]

They've added a bit of noise to the radial gradient to break it up a bit. But essentially, this is all they are doing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a bit of offset inner glow applied to give the top of the logo a highlight opposite the shadow.

Answer (score 1):

> Being that the background is dark, I can't image that they're achieving this with a simple drop shadow.

Your assumption would then be wrong, because they've done precisely that.  You don't need a white background for a drop shadow.  They have a particularly sharp, dark drop shadow below.

As well as the drop shadow, their background also has a subtle texture to it.